# How does Github selectively restrict write-access over SSH?

Tags: ssh, github

If I interact with Github over SSH using the git account, how does it know which files to let me access?

Is it possible on the server to detect which specific key in the authorized_keys file was used to authenticate a user? My understanding of SSH is that once my key is authenticated, I'm logged in as the git user and should have access to everything that user account has access to.

---

Update:

I figured gitosis had to be doing something similar in nature and so I checked out the source. As ephemient says, associating a command with a public key seems like the way to go. You can set it up so that the command receives the user's name as an argument and figure out permissions based on that.

Comment: `man sshd` and read the `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` section, esp `command="command"`.

Answer (score -1):

Of course I do not know what github does but  https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control explains the how.